# dropping columns in multiple excel spreedsheets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there a way in python i can drop columns in multiple excel files? i.e. i have a folder with several xlsx files. each file has about 5 columns (date, value, latitude, longitude, region). I want to drop all columns except date and value in each excel file.

Comment: is it important to drop the columns from the target excel files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you have a folder with multiple excel files:

```
from pathlib import Path

folder = Path('excel_files')

xlsx_only_files = list(folder.rglob('*.xlsx'))


def process_files(xls_file):

    #stem is a method in pathlib 
    #that gets just the filename without the parent or the suffix
    filename = xls_file.stem

    #sheet = None ensure the data is read in as a dictionary
    #this sets the sheetname as the key
    #usecols allows you to read in only the relevant columns
    df = pd.read_excel(xls_file, usecols = ['date','value'] ,sheet_name = None)

    df_cleaned = [data.assign(sheetname=sheetname,
                              filename = filename)
                  for sheetname, data in df.items()
                 ]

    return df_cleaned


combo = [process_files(xlsx) for xlsx in xlsx_only_files]

final = pd.concat(combo, ignore_index = True)
```

Let me know how it goes

[stem](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem)

Comment: this worked perfectly. But how do i then download the data from dataframes_with_only_relevant_columns

Comment: what do u mean by download? do u mean combine into one dataframe?

Comment: i'm trying to download the individual excel files with just the date and value column that we produced. So before i had a folder with 10 excel files that had columns i didnt want. now i have the columns i want andi want to download these in excel format

Comment: ok. the pandas concat should help. unless, you are after something else?

Comment: this doesnt keep the sheet name. i need the name to know the id the value is coming from

Comment: one per file. I want the value colum to = the excel file name. the concat method joins all the files into 1 dataframe. i still want i dataframe for each excel file.

Comment: try it again. i failed to use quotes for the xlsx in the rglob section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208837/discussion-between-tamarie-and-sammywemmy).

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you should define columns you want to keep as a list and then select as a new dataframe.

```
# after open excel file as 

df = pd.read_excel(...)

keep_cols = ['date', 'value']
df = df[keep_cols] # keep only selected columns it will return df as dataframe

df.to_excel(...)
```

Comment: this answer doesn't address the part of the question of how to handle **multiple excel files**